# Left inverse matrix for two different matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Consider two matrices $\mathbf{D}_1$ and $\mathbf{D}_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ $(m>n)$ of full column rank, is there a matrix $\mathbf{D}^{-}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ satisfying $\mathbf{D}^{-}\mathbf{D}_1=\mathbf{I}_n$ and $\mathbf{D}^{-}(\mathbf{D}_1+\mathbf{D}_2)=\mathbf{I}_n$?  Note that $(\mathbf{D}_1+\mathbf{D}_2)$ is a matrix of full column rank. Many thanks! and if so, any way to prove it?

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $\mathbf{D}^-$ were to exist, we should have

$$
\mathbf I_n = \mathbf{D}^-(\mathbf{D}_1+\mathbf{D}_2) = \mathbf{D}^-\mathbf{D}_1+\mathbf{D}^-\mathbf{D}_2 = \mathbf I_n + \mathbf{D}^-\mathbf{D}_2, 
$$

hence

$$
\mathbf{D}^-\mathbf{D}_2 = 0.
$$

But since $\mathbf{D}_2$ has full rank, this implies $\mathbf{D}^- = 0$, a contradiction.